# Server is shutting down every few minuts and MYSQL Daemon is failing to start

Tags: mysql, centos, innodb

I have a problem with my server. It shuts down every 2 minutes. I am using Digitalocean. I have changed to a newdroplet already it was fine for one month. then. I cannot even start MYSQL service.. this is my log:

```
160426 17:06:34 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
160426 17:08:04 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160426 17:08:04 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.48) starting as process 3334 ...
160426 17:08:04 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160426 17:08:04 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160426 17:08:04 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160426 17:08:04 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160426 17:08:04 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160426 17:08:04 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
160426 17:08:04 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160426 17:08:04 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
160426 17:08:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160426 17:08:04 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160426 17:08:04 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160426 17:08:04 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

How big is your buffer pool? How much memory do you have? Who installed MySQL on the server?

> it was fine for one month

What has changed? What is using memory on your server?

Comment: Nothing has been changed.. how can i check my buffer pool? I have 512mb memory holding 2 lightweight wordpress blogs. A programmer installed. i noticed about 50 httpd proccesses which eat up all of my memory. however when i 'killall' httpd it gets back in like few minutes..

Comment: You need a lot more help than you will get from some questions and answers on Stack exchange. Suggest you hire someone who knows what they are doing or move your service to a dedicated Wordpress hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

For a tiny 0.5GB system, lots of things must be dialed back.

50 http processes -- from what?  Apache: drastically decrease MaxClients, perhaps to 10.  Others: ?

128MB is too much for 512MB.  Try 50M.

max_connections should be perhaps 10.

Are your tables InnoDB?  Or MyISAM?
If InnoDB, key_buffer_size = 5M, innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50M.
If MyISAM, key_buffer_size = 40M, innodb_buffer_pool_size = 0.

You have version 5.5.48 of MySQL.  Did Digitalocean change it without your knowing it?